# How to use multiple request handling functions with Node.js Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to do a repetitive auth process in most routes in my app. I decided to give some structure to it and get that repetitive work in a middleware function.

If the auth process isn't valid, I should response and avoid second function to execute, terminating the request.

So, instead of:

```
app.route('/someRoute').all(function(request,response){});
```

I tried something like:

```
app.route('/someRoute').all(repetitiveWork,secondMiddlewareFunction);
```

In particular this is the dummy example I got:

```
app.route('/rutas').get(sum,test);


function sum (request,response,next) {

    if (5>1) {
        response.status(144).end('Fin');
        return next();
    }
};

function test (request,response,next) {
    response.send('Still alive');
};
```

However, when I try to do a GET to `/rutas` I'm not even getting a response. What am I doing wrong?

> ```
> At server side I can see the following when I try it:
>
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
> ```

Comment: You're not calling `next()` in your middleware.

Comment: I tried with `next()` and `return next()` but got not results.

Comment: No, you need to call next outside of your if statement, otherwise it can't progress to the next function in the middleware stack.

Comment: I understand that ... however what I need is .. "if something happens, theres no chance to go to the next middlware, just response and end request"

Im having a stacktrace with: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
 Because of second middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call next() after ending a response, next() is meant to be called to pass the request/response to the next middleware in the stack. Consider this example:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.route('/rutas').get(sum, test);
app.listen(function () { console.log(this.address()); });
var i = 0;

function sum (request, response, next) {
    i += 1;
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        return response.status(200).end('Fin');
    }
    return next();
}

function test (request, response, next) {
    response.send('Still alive');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `next()` outside your `if` statement and also add a return to break out of the middleware's function scope if you don't want it to proceed. `next()` is basically saying, don't stop at this middleware, move onto the next one.

```
app.route('/rutas').get(sum, test);

function sum (request, response, next) {
    if (5>1) {
        return response.status(144).end('Fin');
    }
    next();
};

function test (request, response) {
    response.send('Still alive');
};
```